# Exporting many TIFFs issues in ERDAS Imagine 2016?

Tags: export, geotiff-tiff, erdas-imagine, windows-7, historical-imagery

I have been having an issue with exporting TIFFs on my ERDAS Imagine 2016. The version is 16.00.0000 Build 650. When I need to run a batch to export many TIFFs and it would export one but then it would stopped the program and it would need to closed it.

This is really strange because when I did this the first time it worked fine and then do this again on another different day and all of sudden I am getting have these issues.

I have a lot of old aerial photos and they are in an external hard drive.
I am wondering if anyone who use the software with ERDAS has any issues with the Export TIFFs ? I have looked into Hexagon Geospatial on their site and did not find any issues with Export.

They are all in TIFFs in an external hard drive that has a Forest historical image that was done by flying back in the 1930's to 1950's. It is a black and white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am following this up to everyone. This morning on a new refresh day. I went over to the Export tool to export many TIFF. This one is working without any problems. So here is the picture of what I did this morning.

[image]

I personally do not know why. I think there might be a few glitched I had yesterday. I had to disconnected the external hard drive to allow it to cool it before I went home. I may have left a Windows Explorer folder opened when I ran export tool that may have cause export problems. I had to shutdown my computer when I went home. Also, ensure your external hard drive is plugged correctly. So, just a few unknown that I don't have an answer to it. So that is one thing I would recommend is to clear it out everything before you can try it again.